# HttpContext.User is null at BeginExecute method, for not-existing static files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

This title is messed up, but I stared at it for 10 minutes and I really have no idea how to phrase it better.

I am using .NET 4.6

Exception is thrown at abstract `BaseAuthorizedController`, decorated with `[Authorize]`, `BeginExecute` overridden method.

The line of code looks like this:

```
var userId = requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

The request is about a static file, which no longer exists. More on that later.

The exception is: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   <namespace>.BaseAuthorizedController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) in <path>\Controllers\BaseAuthorizedController.cs:35
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +369
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

`HttpContext.User` object is null. That makes sense, because its a simple static file request. What I don't understand is why `BeginExecute` method is called in the first place, when **no** controller handles the request at all? I am confident that there is no controller, that derives from `BaseAuthorizedController`, which handles this request.

Moreover, this only happens when a **non-existing** file is requested under **files** directory.

To clarify with some examples:

1. `localhost:1000/non-existing-file.txt` - returns `404`.
2. `localhost:1000/files/existing-file.txt` - returns the contents of the file as plain text.
3. `localhost:1000/files/not-existing-file` - returns `404`.
4. `localhost:1000/files/not-existing-file.txt` - calls `BeginExecute`, `User` is null, response is `500`.

What I gathered:

1. It only seems to happen when file extension is present - `.` followed by any symbols
2. It only seems to happen under `/files/`. There is no `FilesController`, only `Files` directory, containing static files. There is also no area or custom route mapping to `/files/*`, which could explain the call to `BaseAuthorizedController`.

Any idea as to what could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a mix of **IIS** and **routing** issue:

1. Routing - in my project there is actually a `FillesController`, however it is registered in a separate **Area**, thus it should not be matched to this route. However it was and this was causing the null reference exception.
2. IIS - I fixed the issue, by adding `runAllManagedaModulesForAllRequests="true"` in `Web.config` - `modules`. Here is how it looks now:

   `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
     <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"/>
     <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
     <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
     <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
     <add name="ClearServerError" type="Suls.Web.Common.HttpModules.ClearServerErrorModule" />
   </modules>`

I do not understand why that fixes, the problem, because as far as I can understand form [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview//) this setting simply overrides `preCondition`.

For some reason I was unable to post this xml-like syntax as code, so I used inline format.

**If anyone has a good explanation, I would gladly accept their answer**